# Cannot create Payal sandbox account and REST API App suddenly

Tags: paypal, sandbox

Before this error occurred, I have created 1 REST API App and 2 sandbox account ready for testing. However, when I login the Paypal developer today, my created app and account are disappeared and keep saying a brief error message **(We’re sorry, but something went wrong while getting your credentials. Please try again.)** to call me try again.

[image: Express Checkout via Braintree SDK]

And I cannot create a new account and new app. Please help. Thanks.
[image: Sandbox Test Accounts]

Comment: You're not alone - the Paypal dev dashboard is broken - affects _display_ of all previously setup apps and accounts (sandbox). Testing on those "lost" accounts seems to still work however, so it _seems_ its a UI/display issue (hopefully).

Comment: Still happening as of Feb 26 at 9:36 AM EST. My PayPal integration is all ready to go, but I never generated my live credentials so I have to wait!

Comment: Things seem to be back up now - dashboard displays all previously created apps, sandbox accounts :)

Comment: Error is showing, but applications are saved also.